# Understanding the different XML Parser terminologies

Tags: xml

Probably this would be a very basic question but as a new person, I am missing it.

This question is not related to any specific programming language. It's general to XML parsing  techniques.

I have heard a lot about various XML parsing terminologies such as DOM, SAX, Pull, Push etc etc and many more.

I tried to search but could not find much.

Requesting you to please explain me in few sentences.

I need to currently work on XML technologies where I would be playing with XMLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through Googles hints, this seems to hit the point in a few sentences:
http://www.wilmott.ca/conferences/extreme2005/xmlparserposter.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The introductory chapter of any good XML book will explain these terms. If you haven't got a good XML book, I thoroughly recommend getting one.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, concerning XML technologies, the study of XQuery and XSLT (v. 2.0) is the key to an optimal usage of XML Data. Parsing can be seen as low level and can be delegated to XQuery or XSLT implementations, the goal is data manipulation.